# Loading multiple audio files with Python/Librosa issue

Tags: python, file, multidimensional-array, loading, librosa

I am hoping somebody can help me with issue I am having. I am trying to load multiple (i.e. 3) audio files and plot them using Python's Librosa library. I can't spot the error here.

```
def main():
pathAudio = "~/Project Data/Practice/Train Music/"
files = librosa.util.find_files(pathAudio, ext=['ogg']) 
files = np.asarray(files)
for y in files: 
    y = librosa.load(y, sr = 16000,mono = True)        
    librosa.display.waveplot(y)
```

The above yields the error:

```
ParameterError: data must be of type numpy.ndarray
```

Somebody pointed out that it might be the type of y which is causing the issue but I can't spot any obvious error here.

Any advice welcome as this one is proving to be a massive time sink for me.

Comment: You are messing up with variable names. `y` is your file name in your `for` loop, but within the loop, you assign your data to variable `y` again. Change the name to something else: `data = librosa.load(y, sr = 16000,mono = True)`.

Comment: Well thats embarrassing! Thank you.

I went with the below but still seem to get the same error. It's progress though. 

data = librosa.load(y, sr = 16000,mono = True)        
    librosa.display.waveplot(data)

Comment: Can you do `print(y)` within your for loop before `data = ...` and `print(data)` after the load to see what the data looks like? It's possible that the output from `librosa.load` is not directly feedable to `waveplot`.

Comment: The output is definitely feedable as I have no problems loading and plotting single files. 

It is when I try iterate through my folder and load and plot several files that trouble begins. 

Printing y returns a str of the file path to be loaded. 
I removed `files = np.asarray(files)` before my for loop. With this, 'data' is of type tuple which is unexpected. it should be loading as type 'float32'.

Very unsure as to why iterating through the folder results in tuples. This is driving me insane!

Comment: What version of librosa are you using? I'm trying to run your code myself with some ogg files.

Comment: up to date! Just installed it on a new machine last week! 0.6.0

Comment: I have provided an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to print the data and this is the output from `load` function:

```
(array([ 1.4347234e-04,  3.3454646e-04,  2.9680674e-04, ...,
        4.7093499e-06, -1.5776950e-05,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32), 16000)
```

which is a `tuple`. You will need to use `data = data[0]` to get the wave data array.

A quick work around is:

```
pathAudio = "~/Project Data/Practice/Train Music/"
files = librosa.util.find_files(pathAudio, ext=['ogg']) 
files = np.asarray(files)
for y in files: 
    data = librosa.load(y, sr = 16000,mono = True)   
    data = data[0]     
    librosa.display.waveplot(data)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Good approach. I am finding now that I can load all three files, thank you. The issue is, all three audio files are plotting on top of each other as they are all stored in the same variable! I suspect I will have to make this a list of arrays and iterate through that to load the plots.

Comment: @CiaranDeCeol The plotting would be another question, but long version short, if you have a fixed number of files, you can set matplotlib grids to display them separately.

Comment: I might give that a go. Thank you for your time and your help. It is much appreciated.